# CSS border padding

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make elements that look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HnRvr.png
but so far I've only been able to make something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAeP6.png
Is there a way to move the border inside a little bit ?

```
span.smallCircle {
position: relative;
top: 20px;
background-color: rgba(145, 142, 142, 0.5);
padding-top: 1px;
padding-bottom: 1px;
padding-left: 11px;
padding-right: 11px;
border: 2px dashed #fff;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a box shadow with the same color

`box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 5px rgba(145, 142, 142, 0.5);`